# Black screen Ubuntu VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, video, virtualization, screen

A few days ago I started working with Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtual machine, exactly with VirtualBox.
The first time I installed it, it looked and worked perfectly. Until one day I turned off the virtual machine and wanted to turn it on, it didn't go. Now when you turn it on, it does its normal processes and then the screen stays black with the Ubuntu logo underneath. I leave captures of the error.
Greetings.

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWQ8V.png)

[First error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7jvy.png)

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96sOJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

### Boot into recovery mode

Turn on your virtual machine.

Quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu.

Select the line which starts with Advanced options.

Select the line ending with "(recovery mode)"

Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.

After a few moments, your workstation should display a menu with a number of options.

One of the options (you may need to scroll down to the bottom of the list) will be "Drop to root shell prompt".

Press Return with this option highlighted.

To mount the root partition read/write, enter the command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

To mount a separate partition, enter the command:

```
mount --all
```

Now run the following commands, to try to recover the system:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
reboot
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case disabling 3d acceleration in VirtualBox settings helped
[image]

Comment: Was running ubuntu gnome on an old, low-end  laptop and this seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Mine has to do with not enough storage, I used virtualbox 6.1 so here's how I fix it.

1. On virtualbox 6.0+ there's a UI to increase the storage size on file>virtual_media_manager,
2. select properties of the disk you want to resize.
3. move the slider or enter new value for increase the disk size.

at this point your disk size storage is increase, but the black screen is still there. Remember we only increasing the disk size not the partition size which our Ubuntu OS reside. Now we just need to increase the disk size and here's how I do it.

1. Download GParted ISO. I download it from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/
2. Mount the ISO image on the disk that you have increase disk size.
3. Increase partition size and it's done.

for detail instruction you can visit website below:
https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2020/09/how-to-increase-the-disk-size-in-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine/

Comment: This is the good answer. Thanks a lot. Notifications on storage size was displayed before the crash